# Compute a limit that involves a hypergeometric function.

Tags: limits, asymptotics, special-functions

Let $a\ge 0$,$P_1\ge 0$ and $x\ge 0$ be real numbers. When answering [Looking for closed form solutions to linear ordinary differential equations with time dependent coefficients.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899727/looking-for-closed-form-solutions-to-linear-ordinary-differential-equations-with/2911948#2911948) we came across a following limit:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak f}(a,P_1,x):=\lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0_+} F_{2,1} \left[
\begin{array}{rr}
 -\frac{2 \imath \sqrt{P_1 a}}{\theta} & 1+\frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{\frac{P_1}{a}}\\
& \frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{\frac{P_1}{a}} - \frac{2 \imath \sqrt{P_1 a}}{\theta}
\end{array}
; \frac{x+a}{x+a+\theta}
\right]
\cdot \theta^{1+\frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{\frac{P_1}{a}}} = ?
\end{eqnarray}
Numerical calculations indicate that is limit exists and is finite.
For example for $(a,P_1,x)=(19,9,4)$ we have ${\mathfrak f}(a,P_1,x) \simeq 15.6191324+24.964897 \imath$ .

How do you compute this limit?

My approach was the following. For small values of $\theta$ we can neglect the term $\imath/2 \sqrt{P_1/a}$ on the bottom of the hypergeometric function.
Then the right hand side reads:
\begin{eqnarray}
rhs &=& F_{1,0}\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1+\frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{\frac{P_1}{a}}\\
- 
\end{array}
;\frac{x+a}{x+a+\theta}
\right]
\cdot \theta^{1+\frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{\frac{P_1}{a}}}\\
&=&
\left(1-\frac{x+a}{x+a+\theta}\right)^{-(1+\frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{\frac{P_1}{a}})}\cdot \theta^{1+\frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{\frac{P_1}{a}}}\\
&=&
\left(x+a+\theta\right)^{(1+\frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{\frac{P_1}{a}})}\\
&\rightarrow & 
\left(x+a\right)^{(1+\frac{\imath}{2} \sqrt{\frac{P_1}{a}})}
\end{eqnarray}
Yet this approach leads to the value $10.86088 + 20.27415 \imath \neq {\mathfrak f}(a,P_1,x)$!!

What is wrong about my approach and how do i compute the limit correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple example:
$$\frac {{_2F_1}(1, c + 1; c; x)} {{_2F_1}(1, c; c; x)} =
1 + \frac x {c (1 - x)}.$$
If $x$ is fixed, the limit for large $c$ is $1$. For $x = 1 - 1/c$, the limit is $2$.

We need an asymptotic approximation which is uniform in $x$. The formula for the case in question is given in [this abstract](http://www.math.sci.hokudai.ac.jp/sympo/130701/abst/pdf/OldeDaalhuis.pdf). After applying the identity
$${_2F_1}(a, b; c; x) =
(1 - x)^{-a} {_2F_1} \!\left( a, c - b; c; \frac x {x - 1} \right),$$
we get
$$\lim_{\theta \downarrow 0} \theta^{1 + \omega} {_2F_1} \!\left(
 1 + \omega, -\frac {4 a \omega} \theta;
 \omega - \frac {4 a \omega} \theta;
 \frac {x + a} {x + a + \theta} \right) = \\
(-4 a \omega)^\omega (a + x)
 \,U \!\left( \omega, 0, -\frac {4 a \omega} {a + x} \right), \\
\omega = \frac i 2 \sqrt{\frac {P_1} a}.$$